# Why isn't the CMD command in the dockerfile running?

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile

I am writing this Dockerfile to generate the docker image.

**-> Dockerfile**

```
    FROM centos:7
    MAINTAINER Glen

    ENV TZ "Asia/Shanghai"

    ADD jdk1.8.0_151 jenkins.war /usr/local/
    RUN ln -sv /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_151/bin/java* /bin/

    EXPOSE 80

    CMD cd /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_151 && nohup java -jar jenkins.war >> jenkins.log &
```

I thought the CMD line in the Dockerfile should start Jenkins already, but when I build the image and execute it, nothing happens. I have to type the following commands to start Jenkins:

```
docker exec -ti 65aeca0b6e3ed9f572e87379e181f6941178ec30d8a38f5c4b5ccd0fee97e92e bash
[root@65aeca0b6e3e /]# cd usr/local
[root@65aeca0b6e3e local]# ll
[root@65aeca0b6e3e local]# ps -ef| grep java
[root@65aeca0b6e3e local]# java -jar jenkins.war >> jenkins.log
```

Is there anyway to change my Dockerfile so that Jenkins and the log can start by itself?

Answer (score 0):

try to use this Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:7
MAINTAINER Glen

ENV TZ "Asia/Shanghai"

ADD jdk1.8.0_151 jenkins.war /usr/local/
RUN ln -sv /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_151/bin/java* /bin/

EXPOSE 80
WORKDIR /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_151
CMD ["java", "-jar", "jenkins.war", ">>", "jenkins.log"]
```

by the way , why not to use the official [Docker jenkins](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins/)